# TypeScript: How to make compilation fail if lacking .js suffix on import for es6 modules

Tags: typescript

I'm using node, and want to use es6 modules to allow for top level awaits.

As has been rehashed multiple places, TypeScript compiles fine without using a relative import with a .js suffix, but fails at runtime.

I'm not here to debate if TypeScript should automatically add the .js suffix to the generated code automatically, I'd just like to add compilation safety to the project. How can I fail compilation if I forget to add .js to my imports?

Thanks!